# Динамический роутинг

Tags: php, laravel

В таблице **articles** хранятся данные. Там есть столбец - **alias**, в который на латинице пишется адрес
до нужной страницы. Например, `primer-url`.

Как на laravel сделать так, чтобы я мог гулять по этим самым алиасам (+ подгрузка нужного контроллера) без предварительного создания роута в `routes/web.php` ?

Из того, что первым пришло в голову -  при создании записи добавлять в конец файла `web.php` роут. Правильное ли это решение ? Или есть иное

p.s laravel 8

Comment: Навскидку. Перенаправляете все на один единственный контроллер - который в себе уже смотрит куда далее идти по алиасу и делает redirect на нужный url

Comment: @phpBear пока нашел такой вариант для себя -
`Route::get('/{alias}',[\App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class,'getPageContent']);`. Контроллер один, адрес любой

Answer (score 1):

Используй динамический роутинг

```
Route::get('/{alias}', function ($alias) {
    return 'Alias is '. $alias;
});
```

Ссылка на документацию и примеры: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters